# Integration with respect to an increasing integrator

Tags: real-analysis

Could someone help me solve this question, please!

Let
$~~~ \alpha(x) = \begin{cases} 
x & ,0 < x \leq 1 \\
2 + x & , 1 < x \leq 2 
\end{cases}$

**Compute** $\int_{0}^{2} x ~d\alpha(x)$

I tried to solve it like this, but I’m not sure

$\int_{0}^{2} x~d\alpha(x) = \int_{0}^{1} x~d\alpha(x) + \int_{1}^{2} x~d\alpha(x) \\ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~= \int_{0}^{1} xdx + \int_{1}^{2} x d(2+x)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that the integral is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral. We can use integration by parts, which states that if either $\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}g(x)$ or $\int_a^b g(x) \mathrm{d}f(x)$ exists then the other one exists as well and
$$\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}g(x)+\int_a^b g(x) \mathrm{d}f(x)=f(b)g(b)-f(a)g(a)$$
In your case, the other integral is much easier:
$$\int_0^2 \alpha(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1 x\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^2 (x+2)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{7}{2}=4$$
Which means that
$$\int_0^2 x\mathrm{d}\alpha(x)=4\cdot2-0\cdot0-4=\color{red}{4}$$

Comment: I think you are right. I made 2 edits here in your answer, sorry. Can you check them? Also, maybe it would be good to explicitly mention what is f(x) and what is g(x).

Comment: @peter.petrov Thank you for your edit. At the end, it should be $0\cdot0$, because $\alpha(0)=0$. $f$ and $g$ are just 2 generic functions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate that 
@Botond

Comment: @Botond

Excuse me mr.Botond

I have another question if you have time, Please! 

I tried to solve it in another way, by using the **Mean Value Theorem of the Integral**

Since $\alpha$ is increasing and $f(x) = x$ is continuous on $[0,2]$, then $\exists ~ c \in (0,2)$ s.t. $\int_{0}^{2} xd\alpha(x) = f(c)[\alpha(b) - \alpha(b)]$ 

I took $c = 1$ and got the result equal 4 

,but is there any clue that proves that I can take $c=1$ from the beginning ?
I mean, it’s just a guess no more no less

Comment: @IyadWalweel I don't think there is a general method to find the value of $c$ in an application of the MVT.

Comment: @Botond yes, I didn’t find any method to find such c. Anyway, I will adopt your solution, Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

$d(2+x) = d(x)$ so there's no problem here.

This integral is just  $\int_{0}^{2} x ~d(x)$

Do you know how to compute this one?

Comment: First of all, thank you, I appreciate that.
Yeah, I know how to compute this integral of course 
the problem was that there are a lot of theorems that I fail to conclude a helpful result of them to solve this question.

Comment: @IyadWalweel This is not correct, because $\alpha$ is not differentiable at $x=1$ (it has a jump discontinuity).